# Boton desaparece despues de darle padding Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic

Tengo este codigo en mi page de Ionic de un login

```
   <ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      <h5>Get the best from our app</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="contenido">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="person" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-input placeholder="Email Address" type="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="lock" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-input placeholder="Password" type="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="forgot">Forgot Password</span>
    </div>
    <ion-button  class="boton" expand="block">
      Login
    </ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Y tengo este en mi css

```
.boton{
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

El problema es que si tengo un padding mayor a 30px este desparece y queda un espacio en blanco. Donde despues del **Forgot Password** deberia aparecer el boton

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar las etiquetas < ion-item >< /ion-item > para alojar el button, quizás metiendo tanto relleno exceda el limite del padre.